# iframe not working. Everything looks correct

Tags: html, iframe

I tried creating an iframe. I have created an iframe before. But this one doesn't seem to work no matter what I do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DSCOVR</title>
</head>
<body>
DSCOVR:
<iframe src="http://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.html" width="100%" height="1000px">loading...</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to jsfiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/mmzj1uge/)

It doesn't seem to work with any other websites either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console.

> Mixed Content: The page at '`https://jsfiddle.net/mmzj1uge/`' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '`http://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.html`'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can't embed insecure content into an otherwise secure page.

Comment: The server I'm using doesn't use https:// only http://

Comment: @sub6resources — That doesn't substantially change the answer. Look at the console. Read the error message. `Refused to display 'http://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: @sub6resources If your server is HTTP, can you provide a link to the page that this code is on (On your insecure server)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the warnings (with Safari), there is one that says:

> [blocked] The page at about:blank was not allowed to display insecure content from http://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/index.html.

Like Quentin said:

My guess is that JSFiddle won't embed `HTTP` stuff because JSFiddle's website is `HTTPS` secured, and if it did, it would compromise security.

Hope this helped!